# What humidity sensors allow the user to configure their I2C address?

Tags: sensor, i2c, humidity

I'm building something that will need to use eight humidity sensors, and I want to use I2C to communicate with them. However, all humidity sensors I've found either have a fixed I2C address, or sometimes they have an address pin to choose between two addresses. The most I've found was the [TI HDC1010](http://nl.farnell.com/texas-instruments/hdc1010ypat/humidity-temp-sensor-0-100-rh/dp/2673331), which has two address pins, so four possible I2C addresses, but that's still not enough.

Are there any humidity sensors that either have three address pins, or that have a fully configurable I2C address?

Comment: sorry, this is a product/component recommendation question, and these are off-topic. Instead, you could try to describe the problem you're trying to solve, like "I can't find humidity sensors with adjustable I²C address, so I'm looking into ways of making my 8-sensor system work; {description of what you've considered}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no humidity sensor with 3 address bits available (at least I don't know any).

Yet, you could use some I2C Mux (example: PCA9548) to switch between the different sensors. Additionally , this will also give you the benefit of lower capacitance on the I2C bus, thus resulting in higher possible speed (although this is rarely required for humidity sensors).